# Comprehensive data migration regarding Android 11 scoped storage and compatibility with versions < Android 10

Tags: java, android, android-11, android-storage, scoped-storage

Android 11 made almost all my apps obsolete because of the Scoped storage update!
Okay, I will start by saying that:

Option #1 - `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` did not work for me even though I am still targeting sdk 29.

Option #2 - `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` also didn't work.

Doesn't really matter though, since option #1 would only work temporarily and option #2 would need to be justified when publishing to the store.

Now it leaves me with Option #3 - migrating all my data inside a scoped storage.

My app basically do 3 things:

- Copy a folder named **Test** from the asset folder into the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` because I need a String path.
- Generate an image and write it to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.
- Reading that saved image from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Now my questions:

1. Since I need a string path, I need to copy the folder named **Test** from the asset folder into the scoped storage? If so, how? Or is there another way?
2. How do I save a bitmap to the scoped storage? Should I follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYQ8AO58Aj0
3. How do I read the saved file from the scoped storage?
4. If I do all the above adjustments, will they work for all Android versions? Or do I basically need to check the android version and use either `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` for <10 and **Scoped Storage** for >= 10?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to switch to `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context`. You can read and write files there normally, with no permissions required.

Comment: `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` That will work for Androi 10 devices. Only for Android 10 devices.

Comment: `Copy a folder named Test from the asset folder into the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() because I need a String path.` Copy to `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) ` instead. You can do that even for all Android versions. But of course you can use getExternalFIlesDir() for all and saving files there is the same code as you used to use.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't need Read and Write external storage permissions with getExternalFilesDir()?

Comment: @zaxunobi: No, on Android 4.4 and higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace all `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` occurences with [`getExternalFilesDir(subfolderNameInScopedStorage)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) - this need to be called on `Context`, so inside `Activity`, `Service` or you can obtain `Context` from e.g. `Fragment` by using `getContext()` method

both methods are returning `File`, which is a directory for storing files (but they have different path ofc), so rest of your code won't change and should work

`getExternalFilesDir` is in API since Android 4.4, so on older devices you may still use old `getExternalStorageDirectory()` method, just make an `if` in proper place - you should have one common (`static`?) method for obtaining main dir for storing files